# Is there some way we can add & remove a class from an element at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, css-animations

I have this ui, which expands when a user clicks on it.
https://codepen.io/ankitzz789/pen/gOMdNKg

I have a css class, named expand which increases the width of the element, on which it is present.

I have attached event to the elements, so when I click on them, they are passed on to a function which then attaches, the required class to it.

The problem is, I only want one element to have that class, which means removing that class from all other elements which are not clicked.

I have tried the following methods, but it's not working.

```
var previous;
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");

for(var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++){
    boxes[i].addEventListener("click",shifter);
}

function shifter(){
  this.classList.add("expand");  // add the class  the clicked element
  previous = this; // transfer the element another variable
  previous.classList.remove("expand"); // remove  the class, from the element.
}
```

Comment: First remove class from all elements and then  add class to the selected element.

Answer (score 0):

just change your function to:

```
function shifter(){
  for(var i=0; i < boxes.length; i++){    // First remove expand class from your boxes
    boxes[i].classList.remove("expand");
  }
  this.classList.add("expand");           // Next add class to your clicked element 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear these codes

```
  previous=this; // transfer the element another variable
  previous.classList.remove("expand"); // remove  the class, from the element.
```

Comment: also it is better to create this feature with :focus

Answer (score 0):

in your case you have two options:

option-1 =>

- this is what i prefer if i were you, you are already using input fields that you can use the focus pseudo in css, it would be like this :

  ```
    .input:focus {
        width: 200px;
    }
  ```

option-2 =>

- using javascript as you did, but you need first to remove the "expand" class of all .box elements, it would be like this :

  ```
    var boxes=document.querySelectorAll(".box");

    for(var i=0;i<boxes.length;i++){
      boxes[i].addEventListener("click",shifter);
    }

    function shifter(){

      for(var i=0;i<boxes.length;i++){
        boxes[i].classList.remove("expand");
      }

      this.classList.add("expand");
    }
  ```

i hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

you must be remove class from all element first, then add class to target element.
so do rewrite "shifter function" like this:

```
 for(var i=0; i < boxes.length; i++){   
    boxes[i].classList.remove("expand");
  }
  this.classList.add("expand");
```